# Give an example of a continuous linear operator $\displaystyle\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|\le1} \|T(x)\|$ such that the supremum not reached

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous linear operator , $X \;,\;Y$ normed spaces with

$$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|\le1} \|T(x)\|$$

Give an example of a continuous linear operator such that the supremum not reached

$$\|T(x)\|<\|T\|\;\; ,\;\; \|x\|\le 1$$

If the space $X$ is finite dimensional the unit ball is compact then the supremum is reached

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please.  Don't write \underset{xxx} {\text{sup}}.  Write \sup_{xxx}.  In a "displayed" setting, that yields the same result, except that it also automatically provides proper spacing before and after "$\sup$" in things like $a\sup b$.  And it's standard.

Comment: @felipeuni : sorry to nitpick, but the word is "supremum".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
T:\ell_2\to\ell_2:(x_n)\mapsto((1-2^{-n})x_n)
$$